# Powershell Expand-Archive Cyrillic names

Tags: powershell

I have this zip which contains one file with cyrillic name

[image]

when I extract this archive using `PS D:\Temp> Expand-Archive .\arc.zip` I have this:

[image]

If I extract this archive not using powershell - all ok, russian name becomes readable.

How can I setup encoding using Expand-Archive?